# JSON Query return result with escaped character

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-json

From the following query I am getting result as :

```
"Units": "[{\"Name\":\"Unit25\"}]",
```

Query is as follow query which reproducing this result, I have simplified the query actual query is used but based selection is this:

```
SELECT (      
SELECT *
  FROM (      
        SELECT
           JSON_QUERY(COALESCE((SELECT [Name] FROM (
                    SELECT [Name] 
                    FROM [TableA]                                                       
                    UNION 

                    SELECT TOP 3 [Name] 
                    FROM [TableB]) [T]
                    FOR JSON PATH),'[]')) AS [Units]
            FROM [User] [U]

               UNION

      SELECT
        JSON_QUERY(COALESCE((SELECT [Name] FROM (
                    SELECT [Name] 
                    FROM [TableA]                                                       
                    UNION 

                    SELECT TOP 3 [Name] 
                    FROM [TableB]) [T]
                    FOR JSON PATH),'[]')) AS [Units]
        FROM [Contact] [C]
         ) [Data] 
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)
```

Expected result :

```
"Units": "[{"Name":"Unit25"}]",
```

How to achieve ?

Comment: Try replacing \" with ". However I wouldn't recommend it. Your application would break serializing/deserializing it.

Comment: Already I am using JSON_QUERY

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that using `JSON_QUERY` before the `UNION` statement somehow breaks json escaping. Probably you can fix your query using `JSON_QUERY` as the outmost statement:

```
select JSON_QUERY(units) as Units from
(
    SELECT
        COALESCE((SELECT [Name] FROM (
                SELECT [Name] 
                FROM [TableA]                                                       
                UNION 

                SELECT TOP 3 [Name] 
                FROM [TableB]) [T]
                FOR JSON PATH),'[]')  AS [Units]
        FROM [User] [U]
           UNION
  SELECT
     COALESCE((SELECT [Name] FROM (
                SELECT [Name] 
                FROM [TableA]                                                       
                UNION 

                SELECT TOP 3 [Name] 
                FROM [TableB]) [T]
                FOR JSON PATH),'[]')  AS [Units]
    FROM [Contact] [C]
) u
FOR JSON auto, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

Results:

[image]